# Getting IS 500.19 error for website even when config file is correct

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis

I've just added an MVC v 4.5.1 framework  website on my new computer.  For some reason, I keep getting the message in the image below.  I've confirmed there is no issue with the Web Config file. Additionally, I ensured all the read permissions were set. Once thing I did notice however, is that it seems to be using  IIS Web Core handler, even though this is a .net framework project. Could this be the issue?  I'm a bit stuck here as the message doesn't provide a lot of information[image]

Comment: Have you checked your applicationhost.config to make sure the bindings in there are correct?

Comment: See if this helps: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webtopics/2010/03/08/troubleshooting-http-500-19-errors-in-iis-7/

Comment: https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/oob-500.html

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly this problem just yesterday. My situation was pretty similar - I installed new SSD and I did clear Windows instalation. So I started with empty Windows and i wanted to see if everything is running correctly. But I got the 500.19 error. Web config was OK, but I still had this error. There were several steps, that I took, so try this:

1. Create a development certificate https://learn.microsoft.com/sk-sk/xamarin/cross-platform/deploy-test/connect-to-local-web-services
2. Allow port 80 in Microsoft Firewall https://wiki.mcneel.com/zoo/window7firewall
3. In Sites - your website click Advanced Settings in right Actions panel. Open Physical Path Credentials. Set it to Specific User. Click Set. Set your windows username and your password ( or if you have an account for this, use it instead ). The point is, that it should have full rights to read the files. (This can be done during Adding new website - in Connect as )
4. Download and instal from [https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/visual-studio-sdks][1] .net Core,  .NET Framework ,developer packs and runtimes
5. Until this point, there was no change. I still got that error. Then i reinstalled .NET Core 2.2 Runtime & Hosting Bundle for Windows and that solved the problem. I allready had it installed, so from instalation menu I selected Repair. After instalation I refreshed my website and it worked.

So ... I don't know where exactly was the error, but this procedure helped me to get it working. Maybe just reinstalling the Runtime & Hosting Bundle would do the trick, but just in case, do all of the steps if you haven't done them yet. Starting on a new computer can be tricky, since you install all of the required SDK's and other things just once. Then you take it for granted, that everything works instantly after deployment.

Maybe it looks like the old good advice, just turn it On and Off, but it worked for me. I spent all day looking for some kind of "sophisticated" (complicated) answer, but this did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Our issue was solved by installing urlrewrite, as mentioned in the comment above by Lex Li. We had installed url rewrite a while ago and added a rule to the site, however it was missing from our internal documentation.  Having said that, it would be helpful if Microsoft could provide more detailed errors for this type of scenario (such as mentioning the missing configuration item) as the exception page above (HTTP Error 500.19) doesn't give much detail as to what is causing the issue.